# Remove alla files named xxxx under this dir

Tags: batch-file

How do I remove all files named xxxx.*.sql under a catalog named src?

I mean that I want to search throw all catalogs under src and remove these files.

del will work but only if you stand in that catalog or point the dir out but all the rest under src wont disapear.

Answer (score 1):

Test this on a dummy folder tree.

```
del "c:\src\xxxx.*.sql"  /s
```